# How to create a folder reference in script?

Tags: bash

How to create a folder reference thanks to that I don't have rewrite the entire path every time.

In other words, how to modify the script to insert the foder name once

and then refer to it shortly?

ie. C:/test

```
echo -n "1 - Split files"
split -a 4 -d -l 100 d:/test/*.* c:/test/;

echo -n "2 - Add txt extension"
find C:/test/ -type f  ! -name "*.*" -exec mv {} {}.txt \;

echo -n "3 - Delete unnecessary characters"
sed -i -e '/Details (spedition)/d' -e 's/Value (eur): //g' -e 's/Number (price): //g' C:/test/*.txt;

echo -n "4 - Read only"
chattr +r C:/test/*.*;

echo -n "5 - Pack everything into 7 zip"
cygstart C:/test/7zip_script.bat
exit
```

Comment: Linux does not use letter labels `C:/path` for paths or directory structures, wondering why you labelled this as "linux"

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a variable i.e.:

```
folder='C:/test/'

echo -n "1 - Split files"
split -a 4 -d -l 100 d:/test/*.* "${folder}";

echo -n "2 - Add txt extension"
find "${folder}" -type f ! -name "*.*" -exec mv {} {}.txt \;

echo -n "3 - Delete unnecessary characters"
sed -i -e '/Details (spedition)/d' -e 's/Value (eur): //g' -e 's/Number (price): //g' "${folder}"*.txt;

echo -n "4 - Read only"
chattr +r "${folder}"*.*;

echo -n "5 - Pack everything into 7 zip"
cygstart "${folder}7zip_script.bat"
exit 0
```

One of the foundations of DRY programming.

Comment: what about bat files in windows? How to make a reference there?

Comment: batch files are different thing than bash. You can check this link for [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_variables.htm](batch script variables)